# Test cases for validating product license...?

Tags: testing

I am having a product and its license is gets validated from server. Can any body tell me how many test scenarios i can prepare on this to validate license...?

Answer (score 0):

How do we know how many unless we know how the validation works? ;-)

1. Well if you server validated based on time try changing the time in the client and valdate.
2. Change system time (future date) , install app and then change the date to current date and then try validating.
3. Enter the same license key (if any) in two copies and try validating

Comment: Thanks shoban. My self got same thoughts. But still looking some more scenarios...your comments are valueble

Comment: Giev us more info about validation. We will be able to help you more.

Comment: 4. Enter a wrong license key
5. How to validate the license without internet?

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to consider using an off-the-shelf license server scheme like FlexNet.  This allows your customer to manage your product licensing along many other licensed products.

Answer (score 0):

Validate whether the license will work for 24 hours or not
Validate whether the license will expire in 24 hours or it will expire in 24:59:59
(Ex: When a license expires in one day then check whether it expires in 24 hrs or same day 24:59:59)